# Proyecto Serenity en Jenkins Dockerizado no encuentra archivo

Tags: selenium, docker, jenkins

Quisiera solicitar su colaboración para ayuda con un error que tengo en este momento con mi Proyecto de automatización con SerenityBDD montado en un Jenkins Dockerizado.

En una de las ejecuciones el debe buscar unas imágenes almacenadas localmente en el proyecto, y montarlas en un formulario.

Cuando realizo la ejecución en Jenkins Local en mi Equipo windows, lo hace sin ningún problema, pero cuando realizo la misma ejecución en el Jenkis alojado en Docker, muestra un error que el archivo no puede ser leído.

ESTE ES EL ERROR ARROJADO POR JENKINS

```js
[CrearCliente] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/Gradle_6.3/bin/gradle clean test --tests RegistrarNuevoUsuarioRunner aggregate
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :clearReports
> Task :clean
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test

co.com.automation.runners.RegistroUsuarios.RegistrarNuevoUsuarioRunner > Realizar un registro de nuevos usuarios.Realizar un registro de un nuevo usuario FAILED
    org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException at NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2

1 tests completed, 1 failed
> Task :test FAILED
> Task :aggregate
```

Y AL ABRIR EL REPORTE DE SERENITY MUESTRA EL SIGUIENTE

```js
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found : /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Validar Paso 3 Crear cliente/src/test/resources/img/CarnetFrontal.jpg
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.106)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '9cc22f20736b', ip: '172.17.0.45', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
```

EL CÓDIGO QUE ESTOY UTILIZANDO PARA LA TAREA ES:

```js
@Managed(driver = "chrome")
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    private WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://IP_DRIVER:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
    
@Cuando("^el diligencia los datos personales adicionales$")
    public void elDiligenciaLosDatosPersonalesAdicionales(List<String> data) {
        //Configuración Jenkins Linux
        this.rutaImagenes = "/src/test/resources/img/";
        this.rutaActual = new File("").getAbsolutePath ();
        this.rutaTolal = rutaActual+rutaImagenes;
theActorInTheSpotlight().wasAbleTo(RegistrarUsuarioPaso2.conLosDatos(data, webDriver, rutaTolal));
    }
    
METODOS DE LA OTRA CLASE:

cargarImagen(SUBIR_CARNETFRONT, datos.get(8));
cargarImagen(SUBIR_CARNETREV, datos.get(9));
            
private void cargarImagen(Target target, String imagen) {
driver.findElement(By.xpath(target.getCssOrXPathSelector())).sendKeys(ruta + imagen);
    }
```

Y LAS IMÁGENES LAS TENGO CARGADAS EN EL PROYECTO

[image: Imágenes cargadas en proyecto]

Answer (score 0):

Se debe realizar la configuración para leer archivos con el Web Driver Remoto

```js
WebElement fileObject = driver.findElement(By.id("fileCharge"));
((RemoteWebElement) fileObject ).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
fileObject.sendKeys(ruta + imagen);
```